# How to improve for-loop over hundreds of thousands of items? -- Actual issue with formatting that many items

Tags: java, arrays, performance, for-loop, arraylist

I have a tree diagram with 300k+ elements which I need to loop over. I was expecting it to take a while, but it was getting to the point where it looked like it was hanging. I inserted a println statement to track where I was in it, and indeed when it got to certain points it was pausing for a second or three, then continuing. Eventually (about 140k in), it came to a complete stop, then eventually self-terminated the program.

I'm trying to make a tree diagram creator and viewer for a project of mine. It's an n-tree, but not all branches will have n-children. In order to align it how I need to, however, I need to make a complete tree with all possible children up to the specified sizes, then iterate over it to check sizes, change sizes, positions, and existences.

```
//ArrayList<Button[]> buttons is passed in
double width = 0;
double height = 0;

Group g = new Group();
Scene s = new Scene(g);
    Button[] array = buttons.get(buttons.size() - 1);
    int temp = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        Button b = array[i];
        g.getChildren().add(b);
        g.applyCss();
        g.layout();
        width = width > b.getWidth() ? width : b.getWidth();
        height = height > b.getHeight() ? height : b.getHeight();
        g.getChildren().remove(b);
        System.out.println(temp++);
    }
```

EDIT (Because I forgot to say this): I first tried a for-each loop, but it was having the same issues, swapped to this to see if it was any better and received same results

EDIT: Primary source of lag has been sourced to either applyCSS() or layout(), but I remain suspicious as it's pausing at seemingly random ones as low as 16k in and sporadically throughout the rest of them until it dies between 170k and 300k

EDIT: I have made my own solution by ignoring placeholder buttons, and thus ignoring almost everything in the tree, but I'm keeping this open in hopes that someone will know an actual solution and post it, so that others can also benefit. The issue as it stands is with figuring out how to applyCSS and layout hundreds of thousands of nodes in order to determine their size

Comment: Why are adding and removing "b" to g.getChildren()? Is it required?

Comment: Micro optimizations: Don't repeat the calls to `b.getWidth()` and `b.getHeight()`

Comment: @Santosh The buttons don't have sizes and whatnot automatically.  In order for b.getWidth/Height() to not return 0.0, it needs to be added to a scene, then applyCss() and layout() the scene

Comment: You appear to be allocating a lot of memory.  And are Group and Scene GUI components?  Trying to display 300k GUI components is asking for a slow system.  Trying being more "lazy" about allocating components, don't display or allocate them until the user clicks or scrolls them into view.

Comment: @John3136 Yeah, probably should have tried that first, thanks. Unfortunately not having any effect

Comment: @markspace Technically,  I believe they're being considered dummy components. They exist to serve as GUI components, but they're never displayed, only used to calculate size. As far as displaying what needs to be displayed, the entire tree needs to exist as soon as the app is opened

Comment: You need to do some timings to see which bit is slow. Adding buttons to a group, doing operations on the group, removing buttons from the group. There is a "smell" here - adding something just to do an operation and then removing it again? Feels like you could add a different method to `Group` to do some calculations without actually modifying the Group.

Comment: @John3136 I'll go ahead and add some more probes. As far as `Group` goes, that's the only way I've seen to do it, although I've only seen a handful of posts

Comment: I guess the problem is not with the loops. It has something to do with getChildren() and remove()

Comment: @John3136 I separated the loop into an add loop, adding all the buttons to the `Group`, then doing applyCSS() and layout(), then measuring them. There were a few pauses in the add loop, in about the same spots, but almost unnoticeable due to how small they were. The applyCSS() and layout(), however, still haven't finished. At this point, I'm assuming those are the troublemakers

Comment: @Yawrf Do you have access to their source? They are obviously gfx ops (which are often slow). What are you actually trying to do here? Get the maximum width and height (all elements)? Wouldn't you add all the elements and layout etc once rather than once per button?

Comment: @John3136 The source of the methods? As in their declaration? And that's what I just did on my last test and it still hasn't finished doing layout/etc after about 10 minutes

Comment: OK, so at this time, I have reverted to my "one button at a time" approach, and I have developed a solution to my problem by checking if they're placeholders, as I can ignore them during measuring, which means that the generation process here becomes a lot simpler. I'm keeping this question open, however, in case someone does know a way to fix it, so that it can help others

Answer (score 0):

Don't think about for-each loop vs normal loop, arrays lists and similar microoptimizations, which may give you a millisecond at most. Iterating a million of elements is totally cheap, what matters is what you do with them.

It looks like a memory leak, your memory consumption seems to increase, then the GC kicks in causing a tiny pause, but it can't reclaim enough memory, so it gets called with an increasing frequency and finally the process dies as it's futile.

Maybe an added and then removed button keeps some additional information, maybe the scene or the group does.

Try `java -verbose:gc ...` or watch the memory externally. In debugger, inspect the components to find out what changes and stays after `g.getChildren().remove(b)`.

---

Consider re-creating the components, maybe use a new `Scene`/`Group` every 1000 `Button`s or drop the buttons completely. Note that no long-term should ever reside in visual elements, so it should be trivial to re-create the buttons from you data when needed (a not-yet visible `Button` is a cheap data structure (and very fast to create), while a button on screen may hold much more resources).

Comment: So I actually did end up trying that, at least the second part of your answer, putting the actual `Scene`/`Group` process in it's own method and calling that method to run 100 buttons each run in order to try and do that. Unfortunately, it had the same issues, in almost the exact same spots

Comment: @Yawrf Then I'd inspect the buttons. I guess, there's some information (bitmap or some other "big" data) stored in them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a enhanced for loop? Here is an example of one

```
for (int YourNumberHere : YourArrayHEre) 
{
    Button b = array[i];
    g.getChildren().add(b);
    g.applyCss();
    g.layout();
    width = width > b.getWidth() ? width : b.getWidth();
    height = height > b.getHeight() ? height : b.getHeight();
    g.getChildren().remove(b);
    System.out.println(temp++);
}
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that. I have, it was having the same issues (Now edited in)

Comment: I also had this type of problem on one of my older projects but I recall it getting slower and almost completely stopping around the 10000th item in the list. Sorry that is couldn't help! Good Luck with your adventures in this project!